# paired t-test for two different samples and measurements taken in two different years

Tags: anova, t-test, paired-data

I measured hourly temperatures of site A and site B in June 2016 and June 2017. I used paired t-test to compare the means of site A & B for June 2016 (n=720) and p-value was 0.07 (significance level α = 0.05).
Then i used paired t-test to compare the means of site A & B for June 2017 (n=720) and p-value was 0.0002
Now, if i want to compare the means of site A & B, using paired t-test, for June during 2016-2017, how can i do it?

case 1:
Do i have to compare data of site A for June 2016-2017 (n=n(2016)+n(2017)=720+720=1440) and site B (n=1440) ?

| No | date-time | Temp-Site A | Temp-Site B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-June-2016 1:00 | 23oC | 24oC |
| 2 | 1-June-2016 2:00 | 22oC | 25oC |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1440 | 30-June-**2017** 00:00 | 21oC | 20oC |

OR

case 2:
Do i have to compare **mean** hourly data of 2016-2017 of site A (n=720) and **mean** hourly data of 2016-2017 of site B (n=720) ?

| No | date-time | Mean Temp-Site A | Mean Temp-Site B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-June-(2016-2017) 1:00 | 23.2oC | 24.6oC |
| 2 | 1-June-(2016-2017) 2:00 | 22.8oC | 25.1oC |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 720 | 30-June-**(2016-2017)** 00:00 | 21oC | 21oC |

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. You are comparing site A and B, right? Are these different sites? If so, why do you use paired samples t-test?

Comment: Hi, Site A is close to site B and i want to examin the impact of weather on the recorded mean temperatures of each site as a result of the different morphological characteristics of each site.